# CURL with special login form

Tags: php, curl

I have written previous curl scripts that successfully handled login/passwords scripts. But I am facing one I cannot break. Here is my code:

```
<?
$login_email = "xxxx" ;
$login_pass = "xxx" ;
$cookie_file_path = "cookie3.txt"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://89.31.145.108/athezza/index.php?php_action=IDENTIFICATION_form&type_ident=b2b');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'login='.urlencode($login_email).'&password='.urlencode($login_pass).'&php_action=IDENTIFICATION_login&type_ident=b2b');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://89.31.145.108/athezza/");
$page = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($page);
?>
```

and the page is the following :

```
http://89.31.145.108/athezza/index.php?php_action=IDENTIFICATION_form&type_ident=b2b
```

Somehow I cannot manage to send sufficient POST elements, even if I think I have identified all of them in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, options `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` must be initialized with FULL path value. "cookie3.txt" is relative path.
Secondly, don't build POST data manually, use `http_build_query()` instead.

So your code should look like this:

```
$login_email = "xxxx";
$login_pass = "xxx";
$cookie_file_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie3.txt"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://89.31.145.108/athezza/index.php');
$data = array(
    'php_action' => 'IDENTIFICATION_login', 'type_ident' => 'b2b', 'login' => $login_email, 'password' => $login_pass
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://89.31.145.108/athezza/");
$page = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before posting the data for the login, first browse the login page using curl so that you can have some session cookies on your file.

```
$home = curl_init();
curl_setopt($home, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://89.31.145.108/athezza/index.php');
curl_setopt($home, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($home, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($home, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_exec($home);
curl_close($home);
```

Now use your data to POST login credential after this.